# how WTF forms dispaly correct value stored in database related to foreign key

Tags: flask, foreign-keys, one-to-many, flask-wtforms

I have 3 tables , Company , city , Sector, company tables has one to many relationship with both city and sector tables

```
class City (db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False) 
    companies=db.relationship('Company',backref='city')
    def __repr__(self): 
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

```
class Sector (db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    companies=db.relationship('Company',backref='sector')
    def __repr__(self): 
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    reg_number=db.Column(db.String(15))
    reg_enddate=db.Column(db.Date)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255),nullable=False)
    tel1=db.Column(db.String(255))
    tel2=db.Column(db.String(255))
    fax=db.Column(db.String(255))
    contact_person=db.Column(db.String(255))
    phone=db.Column(db.String(255))
    email=db.Column(db.String(255))
    city_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('city.id'))
    sector_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('sector.id'))
```

i can create / update  company information perfectly and stored correctly in database , but when i try to let WTF form to display information in update page , it cannot get the correct Sector, City information related to company

my Companyform is

```
class CompanyForm(FlaskForm):
    name=StringField('name',validators=[DataRequired()])
    address=StringField(' addres',validators=[DataRequired()])
    city_id=QuerySelectField("city",query_factory=city_query)
    sector_id=QuerySelectField('sector',query_factory=sector_query)
    reg_number=StringField('register number')
    reg_enddate=DateField('register date',format='%Y-%m-%d')
    tel1=StringField('Tel 1')
    tel2=StringField('Tel 2')
    fax=StringField('Fax')
    contact_person=StringField(' Contact person ')
    phone=StringField('contact person phone')
    email=StringField(' E-mail')

    submit=SubmitField('Add/Edit company')
```

my route to edit information of the company as follow

```
def update_company(company_id):
    company=Company.query.get_or_404(company_id)
    
    form=CompanyForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        company.name=form.name.data
        company.address=form.address.data
        company.city_id=form.city_id.data.id
        company.sector_id=form.sector_id.data.id
        company.reg_number=form.reg_number.data
        company.reg_enddate=form.reg_enddate.data
        company.tel1=form.tel1.data
        company.tel2=form.tel2.data
        company.fax=form.fax.data
        company.contact_person=form.contact_person.data
        company.phone=form.phone.data
        company.email=form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been updated succesffly','success')
        return redirect(url_for('company',company_id=company.id))
    elif request.method=='GET':
        form.name.data=company.name
        form.address.data=company.address
        form.city_id.data=company.city_id
        form.sector_id.data=company.sector_id
        form.reg_number.data=company.reg_number
        form.reg_enddate.data=company.reg_enddate
        form.tel1.data=company.tel1
        form.tel2.data=company.tel2
        form.fax.data=company.fax
        form.contact_person.data=company.contact_person
        form.phone.data=company.phone
        form.email.data=company.email
        
    return render_template('add_company.html',title='update Company',form=form, legend='Update Company')
```

how to make WTF Queryselectquery field  display a correct value that stored actually in database  related to city and sector

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by chnage this in get request

form.city_id.data=City.query.filter_by(id=company.city_id).first()